# Keeping docked right control visually stable when resizing the window from the left side

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the code below, when the `Form` is resized using the `left bar`, the `Button` appears to be pulled away from the `right edge` of the window, even though the `RTL` flag is set. Is there a way to keep the button from visually bouncing when the window is resized from the left?

For example, if the `RTL` flag line is commented out, and the `Form` is resized from the right bar, then the button is visually stable, always appearing exactly against the leftmost border.

Tested using:

- `Windows 8.1 Pro` with Media Center (Version 6.3 build 9600) for `.NET 4.5.2` and `.NET 4.7.2`
- `Windows Server 2016` (versions to be determined).

Animated gif:
[image: Animated gif showing unwanted bouncing effect]

```
public class MyForm : Form {

    private const int WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL = 0x00400000;
    LE le = new LE();

    public Button btn = new Button { Text  = "Button" };
    public MyForm() : base() {
        Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL; // comment out this line and resize from the right, the button stays still
            return cp;
        }
    }

    public override LayoutEngine LayoutEngine {
        get {
            return le;
        }
    }

    // empty layout engine
    private class LE : LayoutEngine {
        public override void InitLayout(object child, BoundsSpecified specified) {}
        public override bool Layout(object container, LayoutEventArgs layoutEventArgs) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works properly on my environment, .NET 4.7.2, WIN 10 Version 1909

Comment: If you rapidly resize the window's width from the left, the button stays exactly in the top right corner as the window size is changing? Also, your Window's `Performance Options` settings have `Show window contents while dragging` checked?

Comment: Yes, it stays exactly at the same location, [no flicker/no jump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf557.gif). And the option is also enabled.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for confirming with the animated `gif`. I tested both `Windows 8` and `Windows Server 2016` and both have a jumping appearance.

Comment: Could you please update the question with OS and .NET version info as well?

Comment: Ideas. Only going from the disconcerting visual: 1) calculation issues on movement?, 2) buffering issues?, 3) bounce seems like a halving as you move left, 4) some boolean being toggled accidentally... no solution to be sure... just some thoughts.

Comment: @Kit Even without `RTL`, simply adding a single `RichTextBox` to a `Form`, e.g: `var rtb = new RichTextBox { Multiline = true, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.ForcedVertical };`, then resizing the form using the left edge, the forced scrollbar has the same jitter problem. The vertical scrollbar pulls away from the right edge when the width is increased, and goes under the right edge when the width is decreased. Just curious, which OS version are you using?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't make the connection to the `RichTextBox` in your question. That's a whole new issue... I'm guessing that thing is its own implementation with its own issues. TBH, I'm not having similar problems, but trying to wrap my head around yours, so my OS is irrelevant.